# How can I track how long pull requests have been open on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

We use GitHub Enterprise for our internal code base. A common issue that we face across teams is the "pull-request review turnaround time" can sometimes be a few "physical days" (many ideal hours).

We're tweaking some engineering practices to prevent PRs from being unnecessarily large and allow for faster turnaround times on reviews. However, I couldn't find anything to help accurately track how long PRs were open before they were merged.

We'd like to use objective metrics to validate some of our approaches to see if we make meaningful differences to the review times and "open-PR duration till merging" is an important metric to track.

Does git/GitHub have anything that could help obtain such metrics? I tried looking but nothing shows up anywhere.

Answer (score 15):

The graphQL API of GitHub could help you to get pull requests metadata such as when the PR has been created (createdAt) and when it have been merged (mergedAt) https://developer.github.com/v4/object/pullrequest/
You could search all pull request with the search query https://developer.github.com/v4/query/#connections then compute the time to merge.

Also you might be interested in this tool https://github.com/change-metrics/monocle as it provides Pull Request metrics for GitHub repositories. Among other various metrics the tools computes the "Mean time to merge" metrics. Thanks to the filters you could set, you could get the mean time to merge for the whole GitHub organization, a specific repository, or developer, or a group of developers.

Comment: `Monocle` sounds neat - I should give it a shot. I guess it could also work for `stash` repos too, no?

Comment: @PhD From what I understand about stash, I guess no as monocle provide crawlers for GitHub and Gerrit only at the moment. It seems stash and bitbucket are the same, well that might be a good addition in monocle to add the bitbucket crawler.

Answer (score 6):

- I was also looking for a solution to prevent PRs from being unnecessarily large and allow for faster turnaround times on review.
- I simply wanted to plot a graph of "hours required to review a PR" vs "Lines of code" to find out what is the ideal PR size.
- I tried Monocle, and although it gives a lot of analytics around the PR out of the box, this simple graph was missing.
- Finally, I ended up writing my **NOT SO NEAT** script for solving this problem.

First, generate a token by clicking on this link https://github.com/settings/tokens

Once you have the token

you can use the following script to store the data required for plotting the in a csv file.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import csv



final_dataset = []
fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"

page = 1

url = ("https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO_NAME>/pulls?state=closed&per_page=100&page=%d" % page)
res=requests.get(url,headers={"Authorization": 'Bearer <GIT_HUB_TOKEN>'})


repos=res.json()
while res.json() != []:
  print(page)
  page= page + 1
  url = ("https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO_NAME>/pulls?state=closed&per_page=100&page=%d" % page)
  res=requests.get(url,headers={"Authorization": 'Bearer <GIT_HUB_TOKEN>'})
  repos.extend(res.json())


print("Fetching PRs, Please Wait")
for data in repos:
  result = {}
  created_at = datetime.strptime(data['created_at'], fmt)
  closed_at = datetime.strptime(data['closed_at'], fmt)

  result['hours_to_review'] = round((closed_at - created_at).total_seconds() / 3600, 2)
  url_for_pr = ("https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO_NAME>/pulls/%d" % data['number'])
  res=requests.get(url_for_pr,headers={"Authorization": 'Bearer <GIT_HUB_TOKEN>'})
  result['line_of_code'] = res.json()['additions']
  result['user_name'] = res.json()['user']['login']
  result['pr_number'] = data['number']
  final_dataset.append(result)


print("Writing to csv, Please Wait")
keys = final_dataset[0].keys()
with open('pr_review_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
  dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
  dict_writer.writeheader()
  dict_writer.writerows(final_dataset)

print("*************DONE*****************")
```

You can now simply import this data into an excel sheet and plot a graph.
you can also use free online tools like https://www.csvplot.com/ for plotting a graph.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: This code was really valuable to get my own analysis of distribution of time-to-close for PRs. There is a mistake in the calculation though: `/ 360` should be `/3600` at the line where conversion from seconds to hours is made.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Github Rest Api to get the details. I have added an example with a sample repo. I think for enterprise editions you have to access the repo information using tokens (https://github.com/settings/tokens). In that case the request uri will be

https://api.github.com/repos/srajagop/page-test/pulls?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

for example

```js
async function timeElapsed(){
   let response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/srajagop/page-test/pulls');
   let jsonData = await response.json();
   let diff = new Date().getTime() - new Date(Date.parse('2019-04-26T05:56:33Z')).getTime();
   let hoursElapsed = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)); 
   return hoursElapsed;
}
timeElapsed().then(data => console.log("Hours elapsed", data));
```

Comment: You don't even use `jsonData` in your code :/

Comment: the response header on that api is of type "application/json".